# Single Layer Perceptron

Tags: neural-network, perceptron

I'm trying to train an SLP with a Heavyside function for a two class problem on MATLAB.
My inputs are (00),(01),(10) and (11). For a target values of (1-1).

This is the code I've tried so far:_

```
 P = {1,2,3,4};
 P{1}= [0 0];
 P{2}= [0 1];
 P{3}= [1 0];
 P{4}= [1 1];

T = {1,2,3,4};
 T{1}= 1;
 T{2}= -1;
 T{3}= -1;
 T{4}= 1;

net=perceptron;
configure(net,P,T);
net= train(net,P,T);
```

and i get this error message:-

Error using network/train (line 340)
Inputs and targets have different numbers of samples.

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Been at it for a while.

Answer (score 0):

instead give the inputs as normal arrays

```
P=[0 0;0 1;1 0;1 1]
T=[1 -1 1 -1]
net=perceptron;
configure(net,P,T);
net= train(net,P,T);
```

Comment: Thank you that makes sense to me,

Comment: Could you tell how I should implement the learning rule to my Perceptron that's been created?

Comment: It gives the exact same error, "Error using network/train (line 340)
Inputs and targets have different numbers of
samples.
".